# How to read an ObjectInputStream without the knowledge of what was serialized?

Tags: java, serialization

Below is a sample code where a `List` , `String` and `Map` were serialized and deserialized. Lets say I need to send the `file` over the wire. How is the receiving client supposed to know that deserialization is in order of List, String, Map ? How is he supposed to know what to cast the object being read into ?

```
public static void serializeBunchOfObjects() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str = "foo";
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo"));
    oos.writeObject(foo);
    oos.writeObject(str);
    oos.writeObject(map);

    oos.close();
}

public static void deserializeBunchOfObjects() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo"));
    List<String> foo = (List)ois.readObject();
    String str = (String) ois.readObject();
    Map<Integer, Integer> mapper = (Map) ois.readObject();
}
```

Comment: "How is the receiving client supposed to know that deserialization is in order of List, String, Map?" The question doesn't make sense. How is the client to know it's an object stream at all? How is the client to know what the objects are being sent *for?* Any client-server system has an application protocol, and both ends are supposed to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to propose a separate solution (or at least a variation) to @Lynch.

When you send messages to your client, do you have a set of defined message types?  If you do, you could define wrapper objects around the message body which can function as a sort of header.

You could define a `FooMessage` which had as members the fields that you want to serialise:

```
public class FooMessage
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final List<String> theList;
  private final String string;
  private final Map<String, Object> theMap;
}
```

Then, instead of serialising the parts individually, serialise the wrapper"

```
final FooMessage msg = new FooMessage(...);

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo"));
oos.writeObject(msg);
```

That way, at least you have an easy way of defining the various fields that will be serialised.  The extra space and time overhead of the wrapper will be extremely small.

Now, you could still employ @Lynch's suggestion of writing a `String` to signify the message type first ...

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo"));
oos.writeUTF("FooMessage");
oos.writeObject(msg);
```

... or, if the number of messages is quite small, you could get away without the string and simply testing the object type:

```
final Object received = ois.readObject();
if (received instanceof FooMessage)
{
  ...
}
else if (received instanceof BarMessage)
{
}
```

A final variation is that you could inherit your concrete message types from a superclass, which contains the type expressed as an enum:

```
public abstract class MessageWrapper
{
  public MessageWrapper(YourMessageType type)
  {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public abstract YourMessageType getType();
}

public class FooMessage extends MessageWrapper
{
  public FooMessage()
  {
    super(YourMessageType.FOO);
  }
}
```

This allows you to do:

```
final MessageWrapper received = (MessageWrapper) ois.readObject();
switch (received.getType())
{
  case FOO:
    return handleFoo((FooMessage) received);
  case BAR:
    return handleBar((BarMessage) received);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first serialize a header telling you what is the content of the rest of your file. This way the first thing you deserialize is the header (in other words a representation of the file structure).

**Edit**

First you have to know which types of objects you will serialise, then you can create a parser for the header.

I can't provide a complete example, but I can help to structure your header. If you manipulate string, list-of-string and map, then your header could look like this:

```
List<String> header = new List<String>();
header.add("list-of-string");
header.add("string");
header.add("map");
```

Comment: Unnecessary. The instanceof operator will tell you what each object actually is.